# Parsing and concatenating multiple json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a few hundred json files to parse (700-800). They all follow the same representation, hence they can be easily concatenated vertically (the second below the first, etc...) into one big single array of objects.  In real life that array will end up with length 2-3million.

What I am doing at the moment is shown in the attached code snippet. Is that efficient please, is there a better way (faster hopefully)?

On my machine with an intel i7-8809G Processor and Windows 10 this code snippet runs in 2.8 secs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--d3 -->
    <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

    var start = (new Date()).getTime();
    var elapsed;
    function my_loader(size) {
        urls = d3.range(size).map(function (d) {
            return make_url(d)
        });
        var q = d3.queue();
        for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            q = q.defer(d3.json, urls[i]);
        }
        q.await(onDataLoad('some value'));
    }

    
    function make_url(i) {
        // This is just an example json. In real life I would have something like:
        // url = "data/json/file_" + i + ".json" 
        url = "https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json";
        return url
    }


    function onDataLoad(param) {
        // do something with the param here if needed. Here it is not used
        var data = [];
        return (err, ...args) => {
            //concatenate them all
            args.forEach(d => {
                data = [...data, ...d]
            });
            console.log('data loaded: ' + data.length);
            elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
            console.log('Elapsed time: ' + elapsed/1000 + ' secs');
        }
    }


    num_of_jsons = 500;
    my_loader(num_of_jsons);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why concatenate?  Why not just parse as you go?

Comment: Every json keeps different data.  I concatenate to have all data in one single big array

Comment: Why would you concatenate though?  That doesn't make any sense to me... parse first, then just merge the data.

Comment: I guess then I haven’t quite understood what you are trying to say. If you have 12 files, one for each calendar month and you want one single file for the whole year, how what I am doing is different to what you say?